# Compare data from 2 tables and overwrite the data on the first one. Apps Script Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have 2 **simple** tables, both with **fruits** & their **price**.
The **yellow** one [see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ba26.png) has the updated prices, but not all the fruits, since not all of them were updated.

[image: updated prices]

What I want is to update the prices of the **white** table with those from the **yellow** table.

My goal is to get an array like this [[1],[2],[5],[6]] to paste it in column B.

[image: See table for reference]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To accomplish your objectives you will have to use a [function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) like the following one. This function will read all data with [`getRange()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns) and [`getValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues). It will later iterate all the current values searching for matching *fruits* with different prices than the updated one; and will overwrite the price when a match is found.

```
function updateFruits() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(
    '{SPREADSHEET ID}').getSheets()[0];
  var updatedData = sheet.getRange(1, 4, 3, 2).getValues();
  var table = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 4, 2);
  var tableData = table.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < updatedData.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < tableData.length; j++) {
      if (updatedData[i][0] == tableData[j][0]) {
        if (updatedData[i][1] != tableData[j][1]) {
          tableData[j][1] = updatedData[i][1];
        }
      }
    }
  }

  table.setValues(tableData);
}
```

Please, remember to update the spreadsheet ID with yours. Do not hesitate to ask for further clarification if you still have any doubts.

Comment: It was almost perfect, thank you so much! I was about to try a different approach but yours worked just fine. thank you!

Now I just have to adapt this code to my actual spreadsheet needs but that will be easy enough